# How to specify the colour number in scale_colour_gradientn of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to show a fixed number of colour in scale_colour_gradientn of ggplot2. In the codes below, I only like to show 7 colour in the legend.

```
dsub <- subset(diamonds, x > 5 & x < 6 & y > 5 & y < 6)
dsub$diff <- with(dsub, sqrt(abs(x-y))* sign(x-y))
d <- qplot(x, y, data=dsub, colour=diff)
d + scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rainbow(7))
```

EDIT with baptiste's comment

```
    guides(colour = guide_colourbar(raster=FALSE, nbin=7))
```

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `guides(colour = guide_colourbar(raster=FALSE, nbin=7))`

Comment: It's a good idea to post this solution as an answer and mark it accepted instead of editing the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks baptiste's suggestion and tonytonov's comments.

I post the answer here

```
dsub <- subset(diamonds, x > 5 & x < 6 & y > 5 & y < 6)
dsub$diff <- with(dsub, sqrt(abs(x-y))* sign(x-y))
d <- qplot(x, y, data=dsub, colour=diff)
d <- d + scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rainbow(7))
d + guides(colour = guide_colourbar(raster=FALSE, nbin=7))
```